# While inside while, giving problem

Tags: php

Good morning everyone.

I have a doubt.

I have two table, behind a data request.
And another product of the application

EX:

```
Request: 1
   >> Plan 1 Value: 10.00
   >> Plan 2 Value: 20.00
Request: 2
   >> enter service Value: 10.00
```

More'm not getting the list thereby placing To other while inside the other.

Repede is not there anymore the request.

```
My code.

 $query = $this->_CONEXAO->prepare("SELECT * FROM disk_request WHERE request_id = :id ");
 $query->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20); 
 $query->execute();
 while ($row2 = $query->fetch()){ 
     echo '<div id="request">'.$row2["request_cod"].'';

     $request = $row2["request"];   
     $query = $this->_CONEXAO->prepare("SELECT * FROM disk_product WHERE cod_request  = :cod");
     $query->bindParam(":cod", $request, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20); 
     $query->execute();

     while ($row_product = $query->fetch()){ 
         // here is list the products of the order is just above an application for various  products can be a 2,3,4 or products on the list ...
         echo '<div> >> </div><div>'.$row_product["product"].'</div>';
     }
 }
```

I would be very grateful for the help ..

Comment: It's already afternoon here, but thanks. And you should properly encode angle brackets as HTML entities (`&gt;&gt;` in this case).

Comment: :) .here is Brazil, we're waking up 10:00 AM, A hug from sunny Brazil :P

Answer (score 3):

Your second `$query` is replacing the first one, which'll mess up the first `while`.

Rename the second `$query` to `$query2` and it should work.

Comment: All appeared request.. More than the products of the order. You know why?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like

```
SELECT * FROM disk_request,disk_product WHERE
disk_product.cod_request=disk_request.request and request_id = :id
```

queries in queries is not really nice and doesnt use sql optimizations ..

If you want to only select some informations, you could do :

```
SELECT disk_request.request_cod as request_cod, disk_product.products as product 
FROM disk_request,disk_product 
WHERE disk_product.cod_request=disk_request.request and  request_id = :id 
GROUP BY disk_request.request_cod
```

Then you do only one loop and you check when the disk_request changed from previous one, you put your `<div id="request">`

Comment: @user628298 I don't understand your comment ?

Comment: So not to list the product request  .

Comment: In disk_product, will have more of a product for an request.

Comment: @user628298 Yes I know, I think you should check about SQL Joints and Group By, You will understand what I mean, Basically you can get results likes `<request1, product1>, <request1, product2>, ... , <request2, product1>, <request2, product2>` ... So when you list them you display you div with request1 at the beginning, when you notice that you passed to request2 you display your div with request2 ...

Comment: @user628298 Actually you could even have like this <request1, (p1,p2,p3)> and <request2, (p4,p5,p6)> using group_concat in mysql .. SQL is so powerfull it can simplify your developpement if you make the right SQL query

Comment: Sorry,  more no going to work out that way. You do not understand how is the list . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You're stomping on the outside loop's `$query`. Use a different variable for the inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

You reuse the $query object, and that's what causes trouble.